# How to find multiple max counts

Tags: mysql, t-sql

Let's say we have these tables:

**genres:**

```
genre_id    genre_name 
1           comedy 
2           horror
3           action
```

**actors:**

```
actor_name    genre_id
stef          2
panos         2
bill          2
panos         2
bill          3
stef          3
panos         3
bill          3
stef          1
stef          1
```

I want to find for each genre the actor who has played in the most movies of this genre(the column of the movies aint needed thats why it isnt there).

The result I want is:

```
comedy  stef  2
horror  panos 2
action  bill  2
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```
select genre_name, actor_name, cnt from (
    select actor_name,
           genre_name, 
           cnt,
           row_number() over (partition by genre_name order by cnt desc) `rn`
    from (
        select actor_name, genre_name, count(*) `cnt` from actors `a`
        join genres `g` on a.genre_id = g.genre_id
        group by actor_name, genre_name
    ) `a`
) `a` where rn = 1;
```

**Note**

Above uery uses windowed functions, which were introduced in MySQL 8.0, so if you are using earlier version, this query will result in errors.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c7aa99/22) implementing the algorithm for [Group-wise Maximum of a Certain Column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html) in MySql.

```
select aActors.genre_id, aActors.actor_name, aActors.aCount as movies_count
from (
  select count(*) as aCount, actor_name, genre_id
  from actors 
  group by actor_name, genre_id
  order by aCount desc
  ) as aActors
left join (
  select count(*) as aCount, actor_name, genre_id
  from actors 
  group by actor_name, genre_id
  order by aCount desc
  ) as bActors
  on aActors.genre_id = bActors.genre_id 
  and aActors.aCount < bActors.aCount
where bActors.genre_id IS NULL;
```